# Sandbox in Large Scalable JavaScript Architecture

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture

I'm trying to understand what exactly should be a Sandbox, in [Nicholas Zakas: Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw)?

I understand that it is "Facade" pattern and should provide simple API to hide underlying system complexity.

1) Should it provide the same API for all Modules? If so, how I can enforce permissions for methods in Sandbox? For example, I don't want to allow ModuleB, to access the method in Sandbox that exists for ModuleA and ModuleC.

2) What is the point of having different instance of the same Sandbox API for each Module? Why the Sandbox can't be single instance that shared between Modules?